# Get div elements closer together, so there is no margin between the rows

Tags: html, css

I want the divs to stay closer together, so the second row isn accurate and the divs have no margin

This is my div css:

```
.post {box-sizing: border-box;display: block;float: left;font-size: 12px;margin: 0 15px;20px 0;padding: 0;text-align: center;width: 310px;background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;border-radius: 4px;box-shadow: 0.5px 1px 3px 0 #d5d5d5;padding: 15px 15px 10px;}
```

and here is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: could you send us a link to test it and take a better look into your styles?

Comment: Please make a fiddle :)

Comment: You probably need to use [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) plugin.

Comment: Or http://salvattore.com/ plugin :)

Comment: This css: `margin: 0 15px;20px 0` is invalid. Please run your stylesheet through a css validator to ensure there aren't other errors preventing your styles from displaying correctly.

Comment: I ended up using masonry :) thank you for the tip! You can answer it with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, **you can't achieve this with CSS**.

You surely need a JS solution, like Masonry : http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't want to use any js libraries, simply create left floating divs (columns).. That way, each post card will display correctly right after the previous one.

Just like this:

```
<div class="column">
    post1, post2, ...
</div>
<div class="column">
    post1, post2, ...
</div>
<div class="column">
    post1, post2, ...
</div>

<style>
    .column {float:left;}
</style>
```